# Unused Global Option (Point Size)

Tags: fontsize

I've been trying to configure the margins on my file for 6x9 paper size, but ended up using the layout for a5 paper. For some reason I have not been able to set the point size since I have made those changes. I get an Unused Global Option error. Is there something I am missing or not seeing? As far as I can see, I simplified the codes by using a5 paper.

```
\documentclass[16pt]{book}%Compile with xelatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}
\newlength\iiindent \setlength\iiindent{20pt} 
\newcommand\secindent{\parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth } 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\leftskip=0cm plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0cm plus -0.5fil
\parfillskip=0cm plus -1fil
\sloppy
\everypar{\secindent}
הקדמת הרב המחבר

אמר המחבר החיבור הזה לא חברתיו ללמד לבני האדם את אשר לא ידעו אלא להזכירם את  הידוע להם כבר ומפורסם אצלם פירסום גדול. כי לא תמצא ברוב דברי אלא  דברים  שרוב  בני  האדם  יודעים אותם ולא מסתפקים בהם כלל. אלא שכפי רוב פרסומם וכנגד מה שאמתתם גלויה לכל. כך ההעלם מהם מצוי מאד וההשכחה רבה. ע"כ אין התועלת הנלקט מזה הספר יוצא מן הקריאה בו פעם אחת. כי כבר אפשר שלא ימצא הקורא בשכלו חידושים אחר קריאתו שלא היו בו לפני קריאתו אלא מעט. אבל התועלת יוצא מן החזרה עליו וההתמדה. כי יזכרו לו הדברים האלה הנשכחים מבני האדם בטבע. וישים אל לבו חובתו אשר הוא מתעלם ממנה. ותראה אם תתבונן בהוה ברוב העולם כי רוב אנשי השכל המהיר והפקחים החריפים ישימו רוב התבוננם והסתכלותם בדקות החכמות ועומק העיונים איש איש כפי נטיית שכלו וחשקו הטבעי. כי יש שיטרחו מאד במחקר הבריאה והטבע. ואחרים יתנו כל עיונם לתכונה ולהנדסה. ואחרים למלאכות. ואחרים יכנסו יותר אל הקדש דהיינו למוד התורה הקדושה. מהם בפלפולי ההלכות. מהם במדרשים. מהם בפסקי הדינים. אך מעטים יהיו מן המין הזה אשר יקבעו עיון ולמוד על עניני שלמות העבודה.

\end document
```

This is part of the output from the console:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [16pt].


("C:\Documents and Settings\Compaq_Owner.HOME\My Documents\Documents\mesilat\me
silat.aux") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd")
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [2]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [3]
[4]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [5]
[6] [7] etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The guide I was using failed to mention this. I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The normal LaTeX classes (e.g. `book`) only accept `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt`. You can't just put in any number there.

If you use one of the classes in the [`extsizes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) package (namely, `extarticle`, `extreport`, `extbook`, `extletter` or
`extproc`) then you can use `8pt`, `9pt`, `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`, `14pt`, `17pt` or `20pt`. For instance:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extbook}
```

Comment: latex HMI is just horrible ! how would I do without this stackexchange !

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing the change the document class you can use `scrbook`. It's a KOMA-script class. KOMA accept any font size by an option.

In your case it is:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt]{scrbook}
```